# Clearing Threats / Actions from Windows Defender for items I have manually deleted?

Tags: windows-defender, metasploit

### Background

I'm on Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363). I downloaded but did not install Metasploit (I'm a CSA). I forgot to add an exemption, and Windows Defender naturally unpacked and picked up on the hundreds of exploits in the msi package.

I decided, for the time being, to just delete the installer package from an Administrative Powershell console with `-Force`. The installer had already been quarantined, it seemed.

Now, even after another full scan, the no-longer-existant threats still appear as Pending Actions in Defender:

[image: Virus and Thread Protection]

I opened every single threat, chose Remove hit Start Actions (below):

[image: Start Actions]

The list *instantly* disappears, no action seems to be taken (e.g., the Antimalware Service Executable doesn't spike in CPU) but I still have an unclear warning:

> There may be threats on this device : 0 threats found

[image: There may be threats on this device - 0 threats found]

Going back to Home and invoking See Threat Details under Virus and Threat Protection, the list is repopulated.

Clicking Start Actions on this tile has the same effect as above: the list is temporarily cleared, but cycling back shows them all again.

[image: Virus and Threat Protection home tile]

### Problem

The threats no longer exist on my device and I just want to clear this list.

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: I assume you have performing a restart?

Comment: Yes and an Offline Scan, so two restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, with no further action than what I described, waiting 2 days cleared the pending items and the tile has returned to a green checkmark, though they all still appear as "Remediation may be Incomplete" in the Protection History.

[image]

**If anyone has a better explanation than "just wait" *please do add it*.**